# When a record is updated, update related records using flow

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, field-update

I'm trying to use declarative methods to updated related records when one record changes.

The two types of objects are related through a junction object, which means I cannot use a process builder to update the related records.

When I try to use the flow to achieve this, and when I set the flow trigger as "New or updated records—flow makes fast field updates", the "Update records" element is not available.

How can I update junction and related objects when a record is updated using declarative methods?

Comment: I'm really jumping into conclusion here but I believe that you have x/y problem. Do you try to update record of the second object being master of junction based on changes from the record from the first object? If that's correct I believe you have design issue here. Basically junction object exist for such purposes. If something on masters is changing, junction should change as it describes affection between two masters. If junctions reach some state which would affect master then master should be updated based on what's happening in junction.

Comment: Agree with the previous comment, but if changing design / model is not an option you could trigger an auto-launched flow with some parameters from process builder flow on your first object

Answer (score 0):

The 'fast field update' trigger is a "Before Save" trigger in the save order, and as such can't modify other records. It's an unfortunate system limitation. In Summer '20, we'll introduce an "After Save" trigger that allows this.

For now, you can accomplish this in Process Builder.